# URL rewrite between 2 urls that are being handled by the same web.config

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I am getting a redirect loop when I try and implement this mobile redirect I created:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Mobile Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="website.com.au" />
                <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://mwebsite.com.au" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This is the catch though, the mwebsite.com.au is assigned to the same web.config as website.com.au so they are handled by the same web.config. This is the way the .net application I am dealing with is handling the request (I cannot split them up, they have to pass through this 1 web.config)

I have tested this by replacing mwebsite.com.au with google.com.au and it works perfectly but for some reason URLREWRITE cannot process the request when it has to inject mwebsite.com.au back through the same rule.

any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is basically saying: if `{HTTP_HOST}` contains `website.com.au` and `{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` contains any of `midp`, `mobile` or `phone`, redirect to `http://mwebsite.com.au`.
As you can guess, `http://mwebsite.com.au` contains `website.com.au`.

To fix this, simply tell your condition that it should START with `website.com.au` using the pattern `^website.com.au`.

So your rule would become:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Mobile Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^website.com.au" />
                <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://mwebsite.com.au" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: You sir, are awesome. It was such a simple thing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your are very welcome! I see you recently subscribed to this website so in case you didn't see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208062), it explains why and how you should accept or not an answer! :)

Comment: ahh Thanks for that @cheesemacfly, I didn't get a notification of your comment, only just read it now. I have ticked the answer now, thanks!